# Create an unnamed column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to append to an existing dataframe an unnamed column with random data?

```
df.insert requires a name of column
df['column_name'] = ... obviously require column name too
```

Comment: All columns are **necessarily** "named", whether you use an empty string, space, None, etc. Can you clarify what you try to achieve? Do you want an **index**?

Comment: @mozway Can you share a link about all-columns are named? I wanted to create a  column-separator between columns of different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [panda's official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html),

> **columns: Index or array-like**
>
> Column labels to use for resulting frame when data does not have them,
> defaulting to RangeIndex(0, 1, 2, …, n). If data contains column
> labels, will perform column selection instead.

If a column does not have a column label, it would be assigned one. So, even if you try something like this, creating a series with no name and concatenating it to a df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"value":[1,2,3]})
column_to_add = pd.Series([4,5,6])
pd.concat([df,column_to_add],axis=1)
```

The resulting column would still be automatically assigned a column label of 0.